# Cannot use data types with jackcess to export DB to csv

Tags: csv, ms-access, jackcess

So I have a program that selects a DB and exports it as a csv. It appears when I export the DB the tab delimitation does not keep any data types. The csv ideally should keep text fields as "####","##"
instead of just ####,##.
Although the fields are "numbers" they have no need to be treated as numbers. This lack of formatting causes a small issue with sorting and I can see jackcess supports data types but will I need to use the cursor to keep these datatypes or can I still use the exportFile() function?

```
public DBTool() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select an access database file to be converted to .csv");
    String userhome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(userhome);
    //chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Database to Convert");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
      System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
      source = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
      destination = chooser.getCurrentDirectory() + "\\output.csv";
      System.out.println("Source: " + source);
      System.out.println("Destination: " + destination);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
}
    }

public void openEDB(){
    sourceF = new File(source);
    long length = sourceF.length();
    System.out.println(length);
    try {
        try {
        db = new DatabaseBuilder(sourceF)
        .setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider("password"))
        .open();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        db = DatabaseBuilder.open(sourceF);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void exportDB(){
    destinationF = new File(destination);
    try {
        ExportUtil.exportFile(db, "TableName", destinationF);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success, .csv created: " + this.destination);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "small issue with sorting"? True, Jackcess does not put text delimiters around *every* text field, only the ones that contain commas, but many other applications export to CSV that way. And Jackcess does not do silly things like removing leading zeros from text fields that "look like numbers".

Comment: The output from my program puts the first account (0) as the 10th account and everything else besides the first ten are in perfect order. So is there a way with Jackcess to output my alphanumberic fields with the " around every field or should I consider something else? I just read in the documentation that Jackcess supports the text datatype but does the export keep the datatype in .csv format?

Comment: (1) What is the field type of the field on which you want to order the results? (2) Does that field have an index on it?

Comment: The field does not have an index and it is alphanumeric but for my purposes every field could be treated as  text so long as the first field is sorted ascending alphanumerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to force Jackcess to enclose all text fields in double quotes when exporting. However, that would not affect the order in which the rows are exported by Jackcess anyway.

When using [exportFile()](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ExportUtil.html#exportFile(com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), Jackcess will export the rows in *natural order*, which is the order in which the rows physically exist in the table (often, but not always, the order in which the rows were inserted into the table).

When using [exportWriter() with a Cursor](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ExportUtil.html#exportWriter(com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Cursor,%20java.io.BufferedWriter,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20char,%20com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportFilter)), Jackcess will export the rows in the order defined by the Cursor. So, if the field on which you want to sort the output has an index on it then you can create an IndexCursor and use exportWriter() with that Cursor to dump the rows to CSV.

If the field on which you want to sort the output does not have an index on it and you are unable (or unwilling) to create such an index in the Access database then another approach would be to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to create a ResultSet based on an SQL statement that has an ORDER BY clause, then use something like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to dump the ResultSet to CSV.

Comment: Thank you. I needed to use the Cursor and to solve the issue of string values I just have another function with some regex that puts " before and after commas. Maybe not the most efficient but I just need it to work and it does in less than a second so I cant complain.